# Is there another way to iterate an identical for loop of dictionaries to infinite?

Tags: python

To be clearer I have a code formatted like the one below and is there a way to refactor it?

```
def func(value):
    # something / break the script when error occurs
    return dict()


d0 = dict()
for k0, v0 in d0.items():
    d1 = func(v0)
    for k1, v1 in d1.items():
        d2 = func(v1)
        for k2, v2 in d2.items():
            d3 = func(v2)
            for k3, v3 in d3.items():
                d4 = func(v3)
                for k4, v4 in d4.items():
                    d5 = func(v4)
                    for k5, v5 in d5.items():
                        # ... infinite
```

Comment: Perhaps look at recursion

Comment: Is there a better way than `# ... infinite`...?  `while True:`?

Comment: @blacksite but you can't do that infinitely. I don't understand this question at all.

Comment: @roganjosh Yes I tried the `while` loop but I don't know how to apply it for this.

Comment: What's the point in iterating through the dicts when the recursion is infinite (or better "endless")? You can just take the first value of each and process in a while loop.

Comment: It's not infinite at all, `break` will apply during error handling at function `func`. I'm just simplifying the code for you to better understand it.

Comment: @a_guest Please note that function `func` will be having a dynamic result each time we call it.

Comment: A better term than "infinite" to use for this kind of situation might be "indefinite". That means that there is some finite bound to the problem, but you don't know ahead of time what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a recursive function:

```
def func(value):
    # calculate your dict and return it
    # return None if error

def recursive_function(data):
    if data:
        for key, value in data.items():
            recursive_function(func(value))

d0 = dict()
...
recursive_function(d0)
```

Comment: Since the OP reports the structure of the problem to be "infinite" (or rather indefinite) this approach might very well lead to max recursion depth error.